# How to ignore changes in submodules during commit?

Tags: git-submodules

I have a situation, where my project consists of many submodules. So, there is a main project and this project has a .gitmodules file and the .gitmodules file has entry to further submodules:

```
project
    -> files-main.txt
    -> .gitmodules
    -> sub
        developer1
            -> file-submodule.txt
        developer2
            -> file-submodule.txt
```

Now, lets say I am a developer1 and make some changes in the sub/developer1 folder. Ofcourse, after commiting the changes, the changes would be reflected in the main git ( project ) which is including the submodules.
My problem is that even if I set `git config submodule.developer1 ignore=all`, the project git still registers a change in the submodule. This is evident by the + sign against the submodule. The only benefit by setting ignore=all is that I dont get to see any kind of changes in the submodule when I run git status. But, this is  misleading, because, I was expecting the command to ignore all kind of activities in the submodule, not just the reporting part.

```
+8b17424f3e30807df0dc782be05d041d0fb26f77 sub/developer1 (heads/MySubmoduleBranch)
```

This is what I did not want. I wanted to just ignore the submodules completely for sometime, so that they dont interfere in the project git. Ofcourse parallely, I wanted to continue commiting in developer1, but just not want to reflect the changes in the main project yet.

Does anyone has the solution the problem?
I would not like any kind of ACL changes for the team, neither a gitlab solution with pre-hooks etc. It would be great to come to a solution locally.